# How to allow method POST in djnago api

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm stuck. When I try use RideUserViewSet I recieve on GET -
"detail": "Не найдено." on POST- Method Not Allowed. Retrieve and Delete is OK.
There are several rides where current user is driver

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('rides', viewsets.RidePublicViewSet, basename="RidePublicViewSet")

user_rides_router = DefaultRouter()
user_rides_router.register('rides', viewsets.RideUserViewSet, basename="RideUserViewSet")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('users/', include(user_rides_router.urls)),
]
```

viewset.py

```
class RideUserViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializers = {
        'list': RideSerializer,
        'create': RideCreateSerializer,
        'retrieve': RideSerializer,
        'update': RideSerializer,
    }
    queryset = Ride.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [rest_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_class = ride_filters.RideFilter
    filterset_fields = ['price', 'date', 'point_a', 'point_b']
    search_fields = ['date', 'point_a', 'point_b']
    http_method_names = [ 'post','get', 'put', 'delete']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializers[self.action]

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset.filter(driver=self.request.user)
```

serializers

```
class RideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    driver = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    passengers = PassengerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    intermediate = IntermediateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Ride
        fields = [
            'id',
            'date',
            'point_a',
            'intermediate',
            'point_b',
            'price',
            'seat',
            'vehicle',
            'note',
            'smoking_salon',
            'animals',
            'kids_seat',

            'driver',
            'passengers',
        ]

class RideCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(write_only=True)
    point_a = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    point_b = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    seat = serializers.IntegerField()
    note = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    smoking_salon = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    animals = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    kids_seat = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        driver = self.context['request'].user

        create_ride = usecases.RideCreateUseCase()
        instance = create_ride(driver=driver, **validated_data)
        return instance

    def validate(self, validated_data):
        date = validated_data['date']
        seat = validated_data['seat']
        date_now = timezone.now().date()
        is_valid_date = date.date() < date_now

        if seat < 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Unable to set less than 0'))
        if is_valid_date:
            raise ValidationError(_('Unable to set past date'))

        return validated_data
```

Using ModelViewSet doesn't help. same problem. Once I solved the problem with http_method_names,but not now.

Comment: Are you sure you call the right URL (because you two different ViewSet) ?

Comment: @TimothéDelion that one `('rides', viewsets.RidePublicViewSet, basename="RidePublicViewSet")` is OK.
`user_rides_router.register('rides', viewsets.RideUserViewSet, basename="RideUserViewSet"` why that one doesn't work. When I try to call I get response 404

Comment: Is it 404 or Method Not Allowed (405) ? It would mean totally other thing.

Comment: @TimothéDelion if try GET = 404, if POST -  405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: What is your `settings.REST_FRAMEWORK` config ? And do you use specific middlewares ?

Comment: @TimothéDelion 
`'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}`
don't use specific middlewares

Comment: Difficult to see the point without debugging the process with an IDE. Are you sure your requests to be authenticated (because of IsAuthenticated permission ?)

Comment: @TimothéDelion yeah, I checked request with PUT and DELETE.

Comment: I'm sorry. Not more idea. But actually with an IDE that allow for debugging, you might get more informations about WHERE an error is raised that lead to theses responses

Comment: @TimothéDelion Thanks